# bash script not waiting for completion of commands when called from java

Tags: java, linux, bash, shell, scrapy

I am running the following bash script

```
scrapy crawl flipkart -a key="$1" -o "$2"flipkart.xml
scrapy crawl myntra -a key="$1" -o "$2"myntra.xml
scrapy crawl jabong -a key="$1" -o "$2"jabong.xml

echo " scrapy completed"
```

The bash script when executed through the terminal is running as expected as in it completes one execution of the scrapy command then the other but when i try to invoke it through java the same script does not execute the scrapy commands.
It executes the shell script as i am able to read the echo data through the input stream in java.

```
String command = "/Users/renny/Documents/WorkSpaces/Scrapy/tutorial/tutorial/crawls.sh";


String[] cmd = new String[]{"/bin/sh", command,key,formattedDate};
//Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);

ProcessBuilder p = new ProcessBuilder(cmd);
Process p2 = p.start();

InputStream error = p2.getErrorStream();
       for (int i = 0; i < error.available(); i++) {
       System.out.println("" + error.read());
       }

BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p2.getInputStream()));
String line;

System.out.println("Output of running " + command + " is: ");
```

please suggest me how i can ensure that the scrapy commands get executed.

In a batch file i think we could have called start to ensure that the commands run in separate prompts is there something similar i can do in bash scripts

Comment: Are you sure your `PATH` is correct such that `scrapy` can be found? What do you get as standard error from that command attempt?

Comment: I would read the error stream and display it. It will probably contain the reason why the commands were not executed.

Comment: I don't get any error when i run the command. I am able to run the script file successfully from the terminal it is able to run the scrapy commands .

Comment: I have added the following code for checking the error stream      InputStream error = p2.getErrorStream();
     for (int i = 0; i < error.available(); i++) {
     System.out.println("" + error.read());
     }

Comment: That way of reading the error stream is not reliable because it only prints the bytes that are available at the time it is called. You should do it the same way that you are reading the "input" stream - using a `BufferedReader`.

Comment: @RealSkeptic Thanks the error stream says scrapy command not found. but i have added it to the bash_profile                                                   export PATH=/usr/local/bin/scrapy:$PATH

Comment: The scrapy command is listed in the path but from the java web service I am not able to run this script                                                                 renny$ echo $PATH
/usr/local/bin/scrapy:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin

Comment: The question is whether `/usr/local/bin` is in the path of the web server process, not your shell process. The web server runs in its own environment. Can you temporarily add `$PATH` to the echo in the script and tell us what the result is?

Answer (score 1):

```
export PATH=usr/local/bin/scrapy:$PATH
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH
```

Adding the export path to the script file solved the issue thanks @RealSkeptic.

Answer (score 0):

By using `start`, you are asking to start the batch file in the background.

Call [`Process#waitFor()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html#waitFor()):

> Causes the current thread to wait, if necessary, until the process represented by this `Process` object has terminated.

Also you will get the exit value of the subprocess. If successfully code `0`, or `non-zero`if error exit code`.